# Notify users from my webpage that their browser does not have the latest update?

Tags: browser

I want to show a warning message to all of my logged in users to my web application if their browser is not the latest version.  So if they are using IE8 without the latest security patch, or if they are using Firefox 3.0 (instead of 3.5 or 3.6 at this point), or using an older version of Safari/Chrome when a newer stable version has been released.

Comment: it would be really neat if there was a free web service you could use to check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [jQuery.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/). It has some constants for all different browsers and the current version. You could maintain a little *database* in form of a javascript file which contains the most current browser versions and which you access from all your web applications.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to collect the user agent string and then do some kind of a lookup table against that list to see if an update is needed. You can then populate a DIV or open a dialog, etc.

I'm not aware of any "automatic" service that tells you if you are out of date, aside from the browser's built-in mechanisms.

Comment: So basically... buildit :D One db with latest version - API is simple - you send user agent string, API will return true/false depending on the string and if it's latest... simple, go for it and then send us link ;)